# Delete a line/row from a csv file based on line number , in C#

Tags: c#

I have a CSV file with multiple lines , and it's loading the csv file contents into a dataGridView,  now I am trying to delete a certain line based on user input, let say on the windows form app user inputs 5 in the text field and clicks the button how do I go about deleting the 5th line from the csv file ?

I am quite New in C#  coding and I tried searching for a way but couldnt find anything which could help delete a line from csv based on line number.

Edit 1:
Csv file looks something like this :

Sym,Size,Direction,Action

asd,25,UP,Add to Watchlist

dsa,35,Dn,Add to Watchlist

tewer,35,UP,Add to Watchlist

few,35,Dn,Add to Watchlist

qwe,35,UP,Add to Watchlist

wer,35,Dn,Add to Watchlist

ewr,35,UP,Add to Watchlist

Comment: Does your CSV ever have newline characters in fields?

Comment: Yes the csv file does have a newline character

Comment: Can you show an example of e.g. the first 20 lines

Comment: I have edited the OP , showing the csv file contents

Comment: So, none of those fields contains a newline. The *file* contains new lines, which separate one record from another, but no individual *field* has a newline in it. Is this correct? An example of a csv file that might have *fields* with new lines might be a employee file where the address has multiple lines in a single field..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the posted CSV, it looks very simple. If no individual field (something between two commas; your example data has 4 fields: Sym,Size,Direction,Action) contains a newline then you don't need to over engineer a solution. Something like this would suffice:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("path");
var without = int.Parse(whichLineToRemoveTextbox.Text);

var first = lines.Take(without);
var second = lines.Skip(without +1);

var complete = first.Concat(second);

File.WriteAllLines("new path", complete);
```

If we read all the lines in, and then the user enters a 5, we Take(5) of the lines, which is 1 line of header and 4 lines of data. We then run another op that Skips n+1 lines, so we skip 6, which is 1 line of header and 5 lines of data, and start from the 6th line. We write the whole lot to file and all on we've lost the 5th line, as requested